# How to keep a local variable for each cluster in spark?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and this is the first time I am posting here.

Currently, I try to implement ADMM optimization algorithms for Lasso/SVM
Then I come across a problem:

Since the training data (label, feature) is large, so I created a RDD and cached the training data (label, feature) in memory.  Then for ADMM, it needs to keep  local parameters (u, v) (which are different for each partition ). For each iteration, I need to use the training data(only on that partition), u, v to calculate the new value for u and v.

Here, if u,v are not RDD, I can view them as a local variable, which is in the title. If (u, v) are RDDs, then I come across a problem to handle two RDDs (training data, (u, v)) in one function. The detailed questions are as follows

### Question 1

One way is to zip (training data, u, v) into a rdd and update it in each iteration, but as we can see, training data is large and won't change for the whole time, only u, v (is small) are changed in each iteration. If I zip these three, I could not cache that RDD (since it changed for every iteration). But if did not cache that, I need to reuse the training data every iteration, how could I do it?

### Question 2

Related to Question 1, on the online documents, it said if we don't cache the RDD, it  will not in the memory. And RDD uses delayed operation, then I am confused when can I view a previous RRD in memory.

### Case 1

```
B = A.map(function1)

B.collect()    #This forces B to be calculated ? After that, the node just release B since it is not cached ???   

D = B.map(function3) 

D.collect()
```

### Case 2

```
B = A.map(function1).

D = B.map(function3)   

D.collect()
```

### Case 3

```
B = A.map(function1)

C = A.map(function2)

D = B.map(function3) 

D.collect()
```

In which case, can I view B is in memory in each cluster when I calculate D?

### Question 3

Can I use a function to do operations on two RDDs?

E.g `Function newfun(rdd1, rdd2)`

`rdd1` is large and do not change for the whole time (training data), which I can use cache.

`rdd2` is small and change in each iteration (u, v).

### Questions 4

Or are there other ways to solve this kind of problem? I think this is common problem, but I could not find any good solutions?

Thanks a lot,
Han.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1
I would say you should cache the first RDD since its not going to change and use u, v as normal variables for your computations and compute them with whatever logic you have in your algorithm.

Question2
When you apply an action like collect(), count() etc, the actual DAG of operations is evaluated and the final result is just dumped to the driver and it is not kept in memory, hence every time you apply an action, all the transformations needed to create the RDD are once again applied, and driver gets the result.
hence, unless you cache a RDD, you are calculating the RDD completely from scratch every time, when you apply an action.

Question 3
Yes, the code you write is just a Scala code(or Java, Python) and you can think of RDD as a collection with lot of fancy properties and is distributed in the cluster, hence, you can write a function which can work on two or more RDDs.

Comment: Question1, if I use the first as RDD, u,v is different for each partition(I think they should be rdd too), if I don't treat u,v as rdd, how could I send the exact u,v to each partition   
Questions2, can you please tell in these three cases which I can view B is in memory?
Question3: how could I create a function working with two rdds? How do they match with each other? (I need this two rdds to be in the same partition)  Thanks